# CE nightly build does not work out of the box

Tags: orbeon

We have recently installed Orbeon Forms stable 3.8.0 CE's orbeon.war and that works out of box.

Because some features do not work in the stable version we installed the CE nightly build orbeon-CE.war, but this one does not work out of the box.

Form builder has some exceptions. Not only the builder fails but the examples too, so Form runner too.

Java exception

java.lang.NullPointerException 
class: java.util.zip.Deflater
method: ensureOpen
line: 421

We are using Linux Debian Lenny 2.6.26-smp, Tomcat 5.5.

Probably we are running into some undocumented requirement for this nightly build...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem identified and workaround:

We use IBM java 1.5 and this is what we found.

Orbeon stable works OK with IBM java 1.5, Orbeon nightly does not work with IBM java 1.5, see previously mentioned zip error.

We then installed SUN java 1.5 and Orbeon nightly works OK with SUN java 1.5., but first there was a problem:

*Exception in thread "exist_QuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space*

And we googled up this thread:

http://orbeon-forms-ops-users.24843.n4.nabble.com/Data-lost-on-quot-Save-Document-quot-td40450.html

> The permgen space is a separate VM
>   setting. It can be   increased with a
>   VM option, e.g.:
>       -XX:MaxPermSize=128m

Which solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the update on this. Is there a particular reason why you were using the IBM JVM rather than the Sun/Oracle JVM? (Most people using IBM's JVM use WebSphere, but you are saying you're running Tomcat.) Would using IBM's 1.6 JVM be an option for you? (I am curious to know if this would also happen with IBM's 1.6 JVM.)

Comment: BTW, when you get a chance, you might want to mark your own answer as the correct answer by clicking on the arrow to the left of the question. This will make it easier for other people reading this to find the most relevant content.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a known issue, and this is something I am unable to reproduce here. Maybe the download you got was corrupted. Try to unzip the war file by hand (e.g. with `unzip`), and if this gives you an error, re-download a new war. If this doesn't solve your problem, could you update your question with more information, in particular the full stack trace for that NPE?

Comment: The problem is not in the download. We verified that.

There is a zip error and it is coming from orbeon's org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.XFormsCompressor. From the stacktrace XFormsCompressor.scala is interesting.

Here is the stack trace:
http://www.eforms.nl/orbeon/summary.htm